# How to get all four Azure web-site pricing tier/compute modes

Tags: java, azure

Working with the Azure Management Java SDK, I can't figure out if a given web-site is Free, Shared, Basic or Standard.

So far I've got these values:

**Free**
Compute Mode: Shared
Site Mode: Limited

**Shared**
Compute Mode: Shared
Site Mode: Basic

**Basic**
Compute Mode: Dedicated
Site Mode: Basic

**Standard**
Compute Mode: Dedicated
Site Mode: Basic

1. Is this the correct way figuring out the pricing tier of a web site?
2. Why there's no differences between Basic and Standard, and how can I get the correct result?

More background:
I'm using Azure SDK for Java ver 0.6.0, using: com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites.WebSiteOperations

After calling get(java.lang.String webSpaceName, java.lang.String webSiteName,WebSiteGetParameters parameters)

I'm extracting a WebSite instance from the response, then extract these properties from:

WebSite.getComputeMode() and WebSite.getSiteMode()

I'm pretty sure it's the same with C# wrappers. Both work against Azure Management REST API.
In case that it's working with C# (which I didn't checked...), then the Java wrappers may have a BUG.

Thanks,
Tomer

Answer (score 0):

The pricing plan can be found under the Server Farm as field name 'SKU' - this not documented at time of writing, nor it exists in the .net/java apis.

The REST call that returns the result is:

https://management.core.windows.net/subscription-id/services/WebSpaces/web-space/serverFarms/server-farm

Tomer